# Does registring to events saves a class from bieng garbage collected?

Tags: c#, events, garbage-collection

If the only thing that `ClassA` does is to subscribe to events from `ClassB` -which is a long living class- like this

```
static void Main()
{
   new A(B);
}

class ClassA
{
  public ClassA(ClassB b)
  {
     // subscribe to events of ClassB
  }
}
```

Does this make `ClassA` garbage collected?